# How to create custom message processor and message store in WSO2 ESB

Tags: xml, esb, wso2, wso2-esb

i am trying to create a custom message processor and custom message store. since there is not much information on the wso2 documentation. i need help in exactly how to write java files for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by extends ScheduledMessageProcessor(org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.ScheduledMessageProcessor) and extends AbstractMessageStore(org.apache.synapse.message.store.AbstractMessageStore).